# Selecting distinct values from a column in Peewee

Tags: python, python-3.x, peewee

I am looking to select all values from one column which are distinct using Peewee.

For example if i had the table

```
 Organization     Year   
 company_1         2000
 company_1         2001
 company_2         2000
 ....
```

To just return unique values in the organization column [i.e.`company_1` and `company_2`]

I had assumed this was possible using the `distinct` option as documented http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#SelectQuery.distinct

My current code:

```
   organizations_returned = organization_db.select().distinct(organization_db.organization_column).execute()

    for item in organizations_returned:
         print (item.organization_column)
```

Does not result in distinct rows returned (it results in e.g. `company_1` twice).

The other option i tried:

```
  organization_db.select().distinct([organization_db.organization_column]).execute()
```

included `[  ]` within the `disctinct` option, which although appearing to be more consistent with the documentation, resulted in the error `peewee.OperationalError: near "ON": syntax error`:

Am i correct in assume that it is possible to return unique values directly from Peewee - and if so, what am i doing wrong?

---

Model structure:

```
cd_sql = SqliteDatabase(sql_location, threadlocals=True, pragmas=(("synchronous", "off"),))     

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = cd_sql

class organization_db(BaseModel):
    organization_column = CharField()
    year_column = CharField()
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @coleifer I'm using Sqlite - it didn't seem to indicate it was database specific in the documentation, but maybe i am missing something

Comment: Note that the brackets in the documentation are there to show optional arguments, not to be actually passed in.  I thought I had done this myself recently but I can't seem to find it - poking around a bit more. EDIT: oops, ignore me, I see now you can also pass in a list of models.

Comment: Can you show us what your model looks like?

Comment: @jimjkelly - sorry - what do you mean?

Comment: What is organization_db?  Generally Peewee revolves around describing your database schema via a Model class, and you'd then do a SelectQuery using that class (and in turn express what you want distinct using that model class as well).

Comment: @jimjkelly - I have edited into the question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So what coleifer was getting at is that Sqlite doesn't support `DISTINCT ON`.  That's not a big issue though, I think you can accomplish what you want like so:

`organization_db.select(organization_db.organization).distinct()`

Comment: Thank you, yes you're spot on.